# SwiftのScrollViewについての質問です。

Tags: swift, scrollview

ViewControllerで、scrollViewのサイズをself.view.frame.width * 3にしています。

初めのViewにUIButtonがあってその上の階層で、scrollViewをスクロールして覆いかぶせています。
そこでUIButtonのtapを適用させるためにscrollViewのuserinteractionEnabledをfalseにして、UIButtonを押しているようにしているのですが、それではScrollViewがScrollできません。

ScrollViewをスクロールさせることができるようにしながら、初めのViewのUIButtonのタップを適用させる方法はないでしょうか？

前提として必ずScrollViewは一番上の階層に置きたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIScrollViewを継承したクラスを作って、hitTest()をoverrideしてみてはどうでしょう？

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

    // ボタンの上かどうかを自力でチェック
    // ボタンの上だったらボタンを返す

    // それ以外なら自分自身を帰す
    return self
}
```